# Centralize Object Initialization - (Insert Event with Attachment on same code)

Tags: trigger, unit-test, attachment, event

I have a piece of code that sets a Boolean (has_Attachment__c) field to true in an After Insert context variable is executed in an Event in which an Attachment is inserted on the same time. The code does what I want, the issue is that I can't find out how to test this. I'm using this centralize object initialization class to prepare all event data for tests:

```
public with sharing class EventCentralizeObjectInitialization {


 public static List<Event> InitTestEvents(Integer count)
 {
    Account account = new Account(Name ='testEventAfterInsertAccount'); 
    insert account; 

    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User']; 
    User u = new User(Alias = 'standt',
                      Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
                      EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', 
                      LastName='Testing', 
                      LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
                      LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
                      ProfileId = p.Id, 
                      TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', 
                      UserName='standarduserEvent@testorg.com');

    insert u; 

    DateTime dt = System.now(); 

        List<Attachment> attList = new List<Attachment>();


        List<Event> eventList = new List<Event>();
        for(Integer x=0; x< count; x++)
        {
            eventList.add(new Event(OwnerId = u.Id,
                                    Subject ='The test subject',
                                    StartDateTime= dt.addMinutes(-120),
                                    EndDateTime = dt,
                                    WhatId = account.id,
                                    Activity_Type__c = 'Inspection')); 
        }

  return eventList;
 }   
}
```

Later I just call this on my test class doing something like this:

```
@isTest
private class TestEventAfterInsert {

public static testMethod void testPrepareEventAfterInsert()
{

    List<Event> eventList = EventCentralizeObjectInitialization.InitTestEvents(200); 
    Test.StartTest(); 
    insert eventList;
    Test.StopTest(); 

    Map<Id, Event> eventmap = new Map<Id, Event>(eventList);
    List<Event> events = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Account.Id, has_Attachment__c, (SELECT Id FROM Attachments) FROM Event WHERE Id IN :eventmap.keySet()];
   }
  }
```

All this is fine, all works like I'm expecting. The question I have is, how can I add attachments to the events I'm passing from the EventCentralizeObjectInitialization class? I want to pass the events coming from the EventCentralizeObjectInitialization on the InitTestEvents method with attachments assigned to those records. 
Would this be possible by using a Map ?
Any help would be great!

Comment: I have been able to go 46% on the test coverage but I still can't insert an event and an attachment together like you will do when creating an event and adding an attachment to that event on the same page. :(  .. any tips on how to test this behavior?